Framer Motion beaks the website in localhost after uptating content
I'm building the website using Next.js, Tailwind and adding simple animations to sections and text with Framer Motion. However, I'm experiencing an issue that slows down my development. When I run my project with npm run dev all animations work perfectly, but once I make any update to the code or animation, seems like I see the initial value for the animation, which is usually opacity 0. I tried refreshing and empty cache and hard reload-didn't work. I can't figure how to fix this other than opening the project in the new port again but it's really annoying.
I'm leaving my code below in hopes that someone can help with this:
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import heroImage from "../public/hero_img.png";
import MButton from "./Button";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import React from "react";

const textAnimation = {
  hidden: {
    x: -100,
    opacity: 0,
  },
  visible: (custom) => ({
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    transition: { delay: custom * 0.2 },
  }),
};

const Hero = () => {
  return (
    <motion.section
      initial="hidden"
      whileInView="visible"
      className="bg-green-90 relative overflow-hidden"
    >
      <div className="max-container flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center lg:space-x-[80px] padding-container">
        <div className="lg:w-1/2 max-w-2xl">
          <div className="mb-[24px]">
            <motion.h1
              custom={1}
              variants={textAnimation}
              initial="hidden"
              whileInView="visible"
              className="text-center bold-48 lg:bold-85 lg:text-left mb-[24px] text-green-10 tracking-tighter"
            >
              Text title
            </motion.h1>
            <motion.p
              custom={2}
              variants={textAnimation}
              initial="hidden"
              whileInView="visible"
              className="text-center lg:text-left regular-18 text-green-10"
            >
              paragraph text
            </motion.p>
          </div>
          <motion.div
            custom={3}
            variants={textAnimation}
            initial="hidden"
            whileInView="visible"
            className="flex justify-center lg:justify-start"
          >
            <MButton
              custom={2}
              variants={textAnimation}
              type="button"
              title="Download the app"
              variant="btn_white"
            />
          </motion.div>
        </div>

        <div className="lg:w-1/2 mt-8 lg:mt-0 flexCenter justify-center">
          <Image
            src={heroImage}
            alt="Hiking"
            className="rounded-[20px] shadow-lg"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="hero-map"></div>
    </motion.section>
  );
};

export default Hero;

I tried refreshing the page, reopening the window, emptying cache. Tried updating packages
npm update framer-motion next and npm update
Nothing works other than running the project with npm run dev again

UPD: this error seems to be resolved after I deployed the website on Vercel. Now on each edit & save the animation does not break
